# gradlew builds, but Eclipse doesn't

Tags: eclipse, gradle

Trying to figure out how to use Eclipse for Java to tinker with some small changes in a complicated app.

gradlew that comes with the app can build the project, and Eclipse fails to resolve the majority if not all imports that gradlew doesn't have any trouble finding.

I tried importing the repo as an existing Gradle project, and as Git with "smart import".
So far this import is no smarter than I am.

I read Eclipse Getting Started and whatever help I thought might be applicable, but that all seems either too basic or too advanced or doesn't help.

The build fails list almost 42000 problems, mostly "cannot be resolved to a type".
So, doesn't seem like manually putting dependencies in the Build Path would fix it.

What else should I try?

Eclipse: 4.12.0

Buildship: 3.1.0v20190501

build.gradle:
[build.gradle](https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/blob/master/build.gradle)

Comment: For Gradle projects make sure to use _File > Import...: Gradle > Existing Gradle Project_. If this does not work, please tell what you exactly did and what you have.

Comment: Thanks. For Gradle import, the Existing Gradle Project is the only option, which is what I did.

Comment: Which Eclipse and Buildship version do you use? Please show your `build.gradle`, your project structure and say which types cannot be resolved from which dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I added what I know how. Not sure what you mean by structure. There are tens of thousands of problems listed. So, I think eclipse can't resolve any dependencies.